# How to do something when a job finished (IAsyncResult)

Tags: c#, winforms

ProgressForm is a Form.
I want to do something when the ProccessingReport method execution finished.

```
IAsyncResult AsyncResult = ProgressForm.BeginInvoke(new Action(ProcessingReport));
```

Now I do something like this :

```
    while (!AsyncResult.IsCompleted)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    doSomething();
```

I can't move the doSomething() operation to ProcessingReport method. Is it possible?Thanks.

Comment: @LightWing: Have you consider using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) ?

Comment: No,I don't want to use BackgroundWorker.But if i have to do it with BackgroundWorker so I will.

Comment: Raise an Event maybe? Or send in a callback Delegate?

Comment: Why can't you move the doSomething() method to ProcessingReport? I fail to see the real issue here.

Comment: I want to know is there a solution without move doSomething() to ProcessingReport

Comment: As far as I can tell, doSomething is not in ProcessingReport. Please explain a little clearer what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: Why not use the 'Invoke' rather than 'BeginInvoke', looks like you just want to block until its finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DoAsyncProcessingReportResult method that takes a parameter like:

```
private void DoAsyncProcessingReportResult(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    AsyncResult ar = (AsyncResult)iar;
    // map this to your delegate (take mine as an example)
    Func<RemoteDirectoryInfo> LoadProcessingReport =
          (Func<RemoteDirectoryInfo>)ar.AsyncDelegate;

    // Then get your answer from calling the EndInvoke
    _Directory = LoadProcessingReport.EndInvoke(ar);
}
```

You call ProcessingReport (taking mine as an example)

```
Func<RemoteDirectoryInfo> LoadProcessingReport = ProcessingReport;
LoadProcessingReport.BeginInvoke(DoAsyncProcessingReportResult, null);
```

I modified my code to reflect yours the best I could determine.  You'll have to fix the delegate declaration to fit your code.